# Detect device has not permanent back button

Tags: android, back, kindle-fire, buttonbar

I'm customizing my app to provide a better experience with the Kindle Fire.

in this device, if you do in your Activity

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

the soft bar with the back, home and setting buttons disappear, and only appear when the user presses the "fullscreen handle" the soft button bar is back on screen.

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html#StatusSoft

I want to detect devices that have this behaviour, this is, devices that have not a physical back button or a permanent back soft button, so I could set up the window differently in these cases.

I'd like to do it programmatically, and avoid having to declare a config property (and thus maintaining more than one apk).

Thanks.

Comment: All compatible are supposed to have "a physical back button or a permanent back soft button" (courtesy of the Compatibility Definition Document). Hence, I don't think that there is anything in the Android SDK to indicate otherwise, as the Android SDK is only worrying about things that are supposed to vary. You can try going by certain device models (see `android.os.Build`) that you know are problematic (e.g., Kindle Fire series).

Comment: Actually, in the Kindle Fire there is always a back button reachable, as the user can show the button bar in fullscreen Activities by pressing the "fullscreen handle". This way I guess Amazon managed to make the device compatible given Google's specs. This sucks, however, as there an extra click involved for such a regular action as going back... Maybe I will have to specifically detect Kindle Fires using android.os.Build...